# Saving large Pandas df of text data to disk crashes Colab due to using up all RAM. Is there a workaround?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a very large Pandas dataframe that I would like to save to disk to use later. The dataframe only contains string data.

However, no matter what format I use, the saving process crashes my Google Colab enviroment due to using up all available RAM, except CSV, which doesn't complete even after 5 hours.

but that also crashes the enviroment.

Is there a workaround to saving a large text pandas dataframe to disk?

I have tried `to_json`, `to_feather`, `to_parquet`, `to_pickle`, and they all crash the enviroment.

I also tried `to_sql` by using

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine("sqlite:///database.db")
df.to_sql("table", engine)
```

I would like to save my dataframe to disk within a reasonable time without crashing the enviroment.

Comment: Hi @Peter, Need your response to my 2 questions: 1) What is the size of  the data-file you are trying to load? 2) What is the size of RAM at Colab you are using? This will help in responding to your question with suitable solution. Are you able to check that?

Comment: Hello @DataFramed , I am not trying to load data, I am trying to save a dataframe to disk. The dataframe was created by loading several files into pandas and concatenating them, then filtering out a bunch of values. The resulting dataframe has about 6 million rows, 2 columns, of text data. Every IO method I have tried in Pandas results in a crash in my enviroment (google colab)

Comment: Hi @Peter, "Dask" is supper quick on writing the big file by breaking it into multiple chunks.  Please check my answer below. I have tweaked the response for you on how to write the file and save it. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use the `chunksize` argument with an appropriate number, e.g.

```
df.to_csv('filename.csv', chunksize=100000)
```

This tells Python to convert the data into `.csv` 100000 lines at a time, rather than essentially store an entire second copy of your dataframe in RAM before dumping it to the disk.

Similar for `.to_sql`: Pandas would write in batches, rather than everything at once.

Comment: to_csv didn't crash my enviroment, but the thing is it took very long, several hours without finishing. Perhaps it got stuck somehow due to memory issue? I'll try it out. I'll try to_sql with chucks as well.

Comment: It's most likely that Python started to use the swap file when your machine ran out of RAM, which works a lot slower (especially if you're using a HDD instead of a solid-state drive)

Comment: The CSV version still took to long. I tried to do to_sql with chucksize, but that crashed my enviroment as well

Answer (score 1):

**Instead of using Pandas method** "to_csv()", **use Dask Dataframe to write** the csv file; it will be quicker than pandas method.
Dask write function will break your file into mulitple chuncks and store it. 
Code:

```
#Reading file
import dask.dataframe as dd

df = dd.from_pandas(pd.DataFrame(load_boston().data),npartitions=10)

def operation(df):
   df['new'] = df[0]
   return df[['new']]

#Writing the file
df.pipe(operation).to_csv('boston*.csv')
```

**NOTE:** Install Dask package before use:

Using Conda:

```
conda install -c conda-forge dask
```

Using pip:

```
pip install "dask[complete]"    # Install everything
```

References:

[1] https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/install.html

[2] https://gist.github.com/hussainsultan/f7c2fb9f11008123bda405c5b024a79f

Comment: Thanks but I am trying to save the dataframe to disk, not read it. Though when I figured out how to save it, this will most likely be the next issue I face. Thanks!!

Comment: @Peter, Please use dask write function as explained above to write and save the file. It is supper quick and easy.

Comment: @PeterForce You can turn your existing `pandas.DataFrame` (the one you wish to write) into a `dask.DataFrame` first, then write as @DataFramed described. `dask_df = dd.from_pandas(your_df, n_partitions=3)`.

Comment: My enviroment crashes when I try to open my data in Dask. It crashes when I load my data files directly to Dask and then concatenating the dask dataframes, and if I load my data into pandas, and then try to convert my pandas dataframe into dask.